# i have problem with Dark Mode Theme Toggle in Next 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have problem with CSS Dark Mode Theme Toggle becuse my toggle function is renderer twice time so the value get back to his default. in react we was just remone StrictMode but in next nothingh has work my toggle function with all file:

```
"use client";

import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const ThemeContext = createContext();

const getFromLocalStorage = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const value = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    return value || "light";
  }
};

export const ThemeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(() => {
    return getFromLocalStorage();
  });

  const toggle = () => {
    setTheme(theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggle }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

the file where i use toggle function:

```
"use client";
import { ThemeContext } from "@/context/ThemeContext";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import "./themeToggle.css";

const ThemeToggle = () => {
  const {toggle} = useContext(ThemeContext)
  return (
    <div>
      <label onClick={toggle} class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ThemeToggle;
```

. I try to use "reactStrictMode: false" in next.config file but it didn't work